# Can you tag a version in SharePoint?

Tags: versioning, tags

I'm specifically looking at SharePoint 2013, but I was wondering if versions can be tagged or if it's the document itself that is being tagged.

Answer (score 0):

The document itself is being tagged, but upon checking in the file, you can add comments that will show up in the version history.

Comment: Where exactly? What kind of comments?